# Running Meltano commands raises an error: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request_timeout'

Tags: python, meltano

Running Meltano commands raises an error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request_timeout'
```

This is happening on a simple:

```
$ meltano state clear

# OR

$ meltano elt
```

Comment: Please add some details, like *OS*, (*Python* and) *Meltano* version, how you installed it, how you're using it, the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: By chance, are you installing Meltano alongside other packages and not isolated in its own virtual environment? If so, I think the error might be coming from the snowplow-tracker being downgraded to a version before 0.10.0 (see https://docs.snowplowanalytics.com/docs/collecting-data/collecting-from-own-applications/python-tracker/emitters/#the-basic-emitter-class).

Try installing Meltano in its own venv (perhaps using pipx).

Answer (score 0):

you need to likely reinstall Meltano .. based on your error I'd assume you installed via PIP .. make sure you upgrade pip on a clean environment before you try again.. I also suggest you do this before you install meltano

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip3
pip3 install zipp==3.1.0 --no-warn-script-location
pip3 install meltano poetry
```